# How to check if value exist in two table in singlequery using sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

Let me explain my problem how to check if value exist in two column from two different table i will post the table structure

Table 1:

```
ID  IS_Completed 
---------------
 1      1
 2      0
```

Table 2:

```
ID    IS_Completed
------------------
 1         1
 2         1
```

if any one of the table in the column IS_Completed has got the value 0 need to return false or else return true how to make a query for this am struggling with as a beginner so can anyone help me Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have redundant data?

Answer (score 0):

Since you posted no code, here is Raw Query that can solve your problem:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_1,TABLE_2 WHERE TABLE_1.ID = TABLE_2.ID AND (TABLE_1.IS_Completed = 0 OR TABLE_2.IS_Completed = 0);
```

If the count of rows returned is greater than 0, return false else return true.

Comment: Alternatively, use an `AND` operator and compare for the value 1. This just inverts the logic of the query given in your answer.